# Pinning site menu clears default list of pinned sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, communities-list

My account is using the default set of pinned sites. If I go to a new site, (Web Applications in this case), and pin it to the menu under the 'more' tab, it will replace all of the default pinned sites.

> [image: default pinned sites]
>
> [image: Pinning web applications]
>
> [image: Single pinned site]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Yeh I can repro that... only happens via the "more" tab of a site, doesn't happen if you "edit" from the list itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6.1.

Previously, the list of sites to show if none were pinned was calculated and saved in the menu view controller and nowhere else.  It would get passed into the pinned site editor so you could reorder and such, but was not passed to the "More" tab.  When the "More" tab pinned a site, it just saw an empty list of pinned sites and added its site to that.

Now I've moved the full logic for sites to display when no sites are pinned to a shared object and am using that to determine if to show the "Pin" option and the list of sites to add to.